# How to change the colours in GTK3 themes

Tags: themes, gtk3

How to change the colors of a GTK3 theme? Is there any way to that? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article describing how to do that using "oomox" app: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/05/easily-create-your-own-numix-based-gtk.html

Answer (score 0):

[**GTK Theme Preferences**](https://github.com/satya164/gtk-theme-config) works with any GTK2 and GTK3 theme and lets you customize the following:

- selected background color
- Xfce panel, Gnome panel and Unity panel: background and text color
- menu background and font color

So install that by the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```

Once installed, launch ***GTK Theme Preferences*** from Dash / the menu, make any changes you want, make sure the "**Custom widgets**" toggle switch is turned on (or else the changes won't be used by your GTK theme!) and click Apply.

Then, you'll have to log out and log back in to see the changes. Unity users can also run **`setsid unity`** in a terminal instead of logging out.

<sub>[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, But there are many things I need to change. I have selected proper icons, but I need to change the colour of icons on panel like Volume icon etc.. Second thing the white colour used for panel background or any nemo/nautilus backround  etc is not pure white. I need to make it pure white. Third thing, the colours are not vibrant, The colour shade is a bit dullish.

Comment: @GauravDighe except colors??

Comment: Hello It worked. For changing colours of the GTK themes.

Now I need to change the size of the panel, size of windows, spacing between the icons,....TO be exact everything looks big I just need to reduce the size of everything.

Comment: @GauravDighe Glad to work. Then it sounds you have a NEW question, please open a new one. thanks